# Циклический сдвиг байтов

Tags: логические-выражения

Как осуществляется побайтовый сдвиг? Есть два примера (слева и справа), тот что слева — нашёл информацию в интернете, как делается сдвиг. Попробовал сделать с другими входными данными, и здесь уже сомнения. Верна ли логика этого «циклического сдвига»? Кажется, что что-то не туда поставил.
[image: описание]

Comment: Разложите несколько карт в ряд и перенесите k правых карт влево.  Вот точно так же и циклический сдвиг на k байтов вправо выглядит